# Proof of Nilpotent matrix with index n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Y is an n by n **Nilpotent Matrix** with index n. Now I want to prove that there exist an n-dimension vector **w** such that

\begin{align}
Y^{n-1}w \ne 0 \\
Y^{n}w = 0 
\end{align}

I know that the eigenvalues of Y are all zeros, and Yw = λw. However, I have no idea about writing down the proof from the features of the nilpotent matrix.

Can anyone help me with this proof? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Nilpotent Matrix $Y$ with index $n$ means $Y^{n-1}\neq \mathbf 0$ but $Y^n=\mathbf 0$, where $\mathbf 0$ is the matrix with every entry zero.

Comment: Yes. That is the definition of the Nilpotent matrix. But I am asked to prove that the w vector exists such that the two listed equations are also established. Is there any way to write down a strict procedure or explicit flow? Thank you.

Comment: Although, it looks quite trivial if we simply put the w vector in.

Comment: Currently, I think deduction might be a way to prove if I set w = (w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) and multiply with Y like Yw from n = 1, n = 2, and n = k, and so on. How about eigenvalues? I have attempted to solve from Yw = λw, but did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Y$ is nilpotent of index $n$, we have $Y^{n-1}\neq 0$. Hence there exists a nonzero vector $w\in V$ such that $Y^{n-1}w\neq 0$. Furthermore we have $Y^nw=0\cdot w=0$, because of $Y^n=0$. As an example of such a matrix, consider $Y=J(n)$, a full Jordan block of size $n\times n$.

Comment: Thank you for this proof. 
I noticed that you write Y^{n-1}w = 0, should not it be Y^{n-1}w != 0?

Comment: @Sonamu Yes, thank you!